# Facebook app URL does not go to the right place

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

I am trying to open a facebook page from my app in Facebook app via URL "fb://page/{pageid}" but it is not directing to the page, the facebook app's page is not changed with this URL?

I am using the latest facebook sdk for ios.

Comment: Have you tried opening your URL in Mobile Safari?  Does it launch the Facebook app and load the correct page when you try it that way?

Comment: i tried it but it does not load the page in facebook app, the app screen remains unchanged.

Comment: hey @lgy, do have any information regarding it

Comment: I just removed the facebook API related tag since this is a question about how to use facebook's client app for the iPhone, as far as I can see the question is off topic and in general you shouldn't rely on undocumented behaviour of third-party apps when writing your own

Comment: but i can see the "fb://profile/{fbid}" works pretty good, it is also not documented

Comment: yes, and that could stop working at any time, you're relying on Facebook's app not changing how it works internally which is dangerous IMO

Comment: so what do suggest how should i redirect the facebook app to any facebook page, you might not feel good about me asking you this, but as you can see my reputation i just don't know what to do, please point me in a direction, thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help answer your question.. I just figured it out and i'm posting it everywhere I can. It works currently under facebook ios 5.0.1 for iPhone.. haven't tried it in iPad yet.

The url is fb://profile/132753734806

NOW the important part is that number. That links to one of my clients, Charles Scott. HOWEVER, that's not their FBID or Page ID.. their Page ID is 10150348920319807

so you would think it should be fb://profile/10150348920319807 but that gives me an error.

Here's how you get the correct code.. click on any of your page's photos.. here's an example for my client https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150348920319807&set=a.10150348920314807.356942.132753734806&type=1&theater

if you notice the FBID that does not work follows fbid= in that URL.. the number you WANT is just before the &type=1theater but following that last period. 132753734806 is the correct code to punch in after fb://profile/